# Get And Append ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hey I tried this code for my project and it returns some bad results. getting the last Id does not work properly .

```
function regionDropDownChanged() {
    var selectedRegionId = getRegionDropDown();
    if (selectedRegionId !== null) {
        var val = selectedRegionId[selectedRegionId.length - 1];
        alert(val);
    } else return;

    $.get("/Common/JsonFunction/GetEnterprisesOfRegion", { regionId: val }, function (fields) {
        fillDropDown(fields, getEnterpriseDropDown());
        enableEnterpriseDropDown();
    });
}
```

Also enableEnterpriseDropDown() Dropdown does not work after selecting IDs.

```
 function enableEnterpriseDropDown() {
    var enterpriseDropDown = getEnterpriseDropDown();
    $(enterpriseDropDown).prop('disabled', false);
 }
```

other methods that I use in my project

```
function getRegionDropDown() {
    var dropDown = $("#RegionId").val();
    return dropDown;
}

function getEnterpriseDropDown() {
    var dropDown = $("#EnterpriseId");
    return dropDown;
}
```

remember that I use Choosen Plugin.

Comment: can you add more details to your question, a jsfiddle will be good.

Comment: Creating Fiddle will be hard for this project . its so huge code

Comment: @MehdiKhalifeh We aren't saying to create fiddle for the complete project. Just create fiddle for this part and reproduce the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using array of `selectedRegionId` but it is a value, as you have called `getRegionDropDown()` which returns a `single value`.

```
var selectedRegionId = getRegionDropDown();
```

So,
 you may get `undefined` in `alert` in these lines

```
var val = selectedRegionId[selectedRegionId.length - 1];
alert(val);
```

If you create a **Fiddle** then it would be better to `solve you problem`.

Comment: I don't get undefined in my alert. I get a last id and after some alerts it will be confused and return me some unexpected values

And also creating fiddle will be hard for this project.I have huge amount of codes